# SSH'ing into Windows VirtualBox with Vagrant

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant

I am running vagrant 1.3.5 on OSX 10.9. I have a Windows Server 2008 VM installed via VirtualBox. I am trying to set it up so I can ssh into Windows Server 2008 box using vagrant. The steps I am trying to take in order to do that are as follows.

- Install Windows Server 2008 on virtual box
- Install virtualbox guest additions
- Install cygwin and openSSH
- Create a vagrant box using `vagrant package --base Server2008`
- Edit my VagrantFile to account for this new change

> ```
>  config.vm.define "worker" do |worker|
>     worker.vm.box = "windows.box"
>     worker.vm.box_url = "~/boxes/windows.box"
>   end
> ```

- Lastly, call vagrant up, vagrant ssh.

I have completed all these steps. When I call `vagrant up` it says it is initializing the windows worker, I look in virtualbox and see that it is indeed running. It hangs here and I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to make it stop. When I call `vagrant ssh` it just hangs. What do I need to do to get ssh access to a windows virtual machine w/ vagrant?

Comment: open port 22 in the windows server firewall?

Comment: I love you @lain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to open port 22 on you windows server instance.